# Triple-grave blocks show differently on mobile

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, mobile-web

On the mobile site, the following code block is displayed as a single line.

`This
is
one
line`

On the desktop version of StackOverflow, it shows as multiple lines. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595519) uses a triple-grave block, and it shows on multiple lines on the desktop site, but as a single line on the mobile site.

Edit: I thought I saw it as one line for desktop Meta, but it's (currently?) showing as four lines.

Comment: The number of backticks doesn't matter (I just checked), it's any inline code. Also shows as a single line on the iOS app. Code blocks should be used for multi line code anyway so I'd say the bug is that it does show as multi line at all.

Comment: Code blocks have to be taken literally, so a line end in the inline code should be a line end in the end result. @cai

Comment: [The FAQ disagrees](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/307988)